# Combine VLOOKUP and SUMIF in one step

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

What I want to do (if possible) is sum each metric of each transaction with a common customer_id in ONE STEP. The output should look like the "DESIRED OUTPUT" sheet. I know some sort of lookup will need to be used to reference the "CUSTOMER LOOKUP" table.

I can see how to accomplish this using VLOOKUP then SUMIF (or the other way around), but I would like to accomplish it using a single formula if possible.

---

TRANSACTIONS

```
transaction  customer_id    metric_1    metric_2
1            1              0           564
2            1              0           762
3            1              5.305       8367
4            2              0           150
5            2              3.125       4109
6            2              6.18        1853
7            3              0           61
8            3              0           1
9            3              0           4
```

---

CUSTOMER LOOKUP

```
customer_id   customer_name     
1             XXX       
2             YYY       
3             ZZZ
```

---

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
customer_name   metric_1    metric_2    
XXX             5.305       9693    
YYY             9.305       6112    
ZZZ             0            66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it can be done with one formula. This is a very common scenario and is typically solved by adding a Vlookup column to the first table to show the customer name.

Then you can build a pivot table with a few clicks.

I guess, since using a pivot table does not involve formulas, the only formula you need is the Vlookup. So, yes, it can be done with one formula ;-)

[image]